# How to access or export app data on an IOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, music, data-recovery

I have the [Bandcamp](https://bandcamp.com/) app installed on my iPhone. This is a music app for indie artists. The Bandcamp app has a section of "downloads" which are songs I have downloaded to the device. Some of these songs are rare and from an artist that is no longer on Bandcamp. I cannot access these songs through the Bandcamp web application anymore and are only available cached and downloaded on my iPhone. I would like to export these songs off my phone for backup and archival.

I have tried using [Imazing](https://imazing.com/download/macos) to access the app data files however the song data seems hidden or unlisted for Imazing to access. I'm looking for other ideas on this data recovery.

Answer (score 1):

Through the File system view in iMazing, you should be able to view the data.

Another option which most definitely should work is to back your device with iMazing and then explore the backup in iMazing, this way, you will be able to access all the data you were previously unable to access. Make sure when you are viewing data, you chose your newest backup instead of your phone.

Third option is if second option doesn't work, after backing up your phone, attempt to export the Bandcamp app and explore and unzip the file using [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org) or winrar and you should find the data.

Fourth option is if this app allows it's data to be viewed via iTunes, you should be able to find the Bandcamp app under the "File sharing" option of iTunes where you can freely export the data. This however depends on the app developers and whether if they allow you to view this data you want.